# Confused with the results of the code that I modified for synchronization in java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

This is the original code:

```
// Demonstrating multithreading and thread synchronization in Java
public class ForkExample implements Runnable {

    int i; // the ID of the thread, so we can control behavior
    boolean busy; // the flag, Thread 1 will wait until Thread 0 is no longer busy before continuing
    ForkExample other; // reference to the other thread we will synchronize on. This is needed so we can control behavior.

    // create the runnable object
    public ForkExample(int i, ForkExample other) {
        this.i = i; // set the thread ID (0 or 1)
        if (i == 0)
            busy = true; // set the busy flag so Thread 1 waits for Thread 0
        else
            this.other = other;
    }

    // synchronized method to test if thread is busy or not
    public synchronized boolean isBusy() {
        return busy;
    } // What happens if this isn't synchronized? 

    // run method needed by runnable interface
    public void run() {
        if(i == 0) // 1st thread, sleep for a while, then notify threads waiting
            try {
                Thread.sleep(4000); // What happens if you put this sleep inside the synchronized block?
                synchronized(this) {
                    notify(); // notify() will only notify threads waiting on *this* object;
                }
                Thread.sleep(4000); // What happens if you put this sleep inside the synchronized block?
                synchronized(this) {
                    busy = false; // must synchronize while editing the flag
                    notify(); // notify() will only notify threads waiting on *this* object;
                }
            } catch(InterruptedException tie) {
                tie.printStackTrace();
            }
        else {
            while(other.isBusy()) { // check if other thread is still working
                System.out.println("Waiting!");
                // must sychnronize to wait on other object
                try {
                    synchronized(other) {
                        other.wait();
                    }
                } // note we have synchronized on the object we are going to wait on
                catch(InterruptedException tie) {
                    tie.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Finished!");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ForkExample t1 = new ForkExample(0, null);
        ForkExample t2 = new ForkExample(1, t1);
        (new Thread(t2)).start();
        (new Thread(t1)).start();
    }

}
```

This is the original code with my modifications:

```
// Demonstrating multithreading and thread synchronization in Java
public class ForkExample implements Runnable {

    // the ID of the thread, so we can control behavior
    int i;
    // the flag, Thread 1 will wait until Thread 0 is no longer busy before continuing
    boolean busy;
    // reference to the other thread we will synchronize on. This is needed so we can control behavior.
    ForkExample other;

    // create the runnable object
    public ForkExample(int i, ForkExample other) {
        this.i = i; // set the thread ID (0 or 1)
        if (i == 0)
            busy = true; // set the busy flag so Thread 1 waits for Thread 0
        else
            this.other = other;
    }

    // synchronized method to test if thread is busy or not
    public boolean isBusy() {
        if (busy) /*** Added if/else statement to tell user if the thread is still busy. ***/
            System.out.print("Still busy, ");
        else
            System.out.print("Thread is no longer busy, ");
        return busy; 
    } // What happens if this isn't synchronized?
    /*** Method still works even without being synchronized ***/

    // run method needed by runnable interface
    public void run() {
        if(i == 0) // 1st thread, sleep for a while, then notify threads waiting
            try {
                synchronized(this) {
                    Thread.sleep(4000); // What happens if you put this sleep inside the synchronized block?
                    /*** All statements in this block still goes through after notify(), but t1 is asleep ***/
                    System.out.println("yo");
                    notify(); // notify() will only notify threads waiting on *this* object;
                    /*** This notify doesn't work ***/
                    System.out.println("sup");
                }
                System.out.println("stop synchronization");
                /*** somehow forces synchronized(this) as another method call ***/
                synchronized(this) {
                    System.out.println("hey");
                    Thread.sleep(1000); // What happens if you put this sleep inside the synchronized block?
                    System.out.println("hello");
                    busy = false; // must synchronize while editing the flag
                    notify(); // notify() will only notify threads waiting on *this* object;
                    /*** This notify does not work either ***/
                    System.out.println("que?");
                }
                synchronized(this) {
                    System.out.println("yes");
                    notify();
                    /*** This notify works if the "stop synchronization statement exists ***/
                }
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                synchronized(this) {
                    System.out.println("hey again");
                    notify();
                }
                /*** Other thread finally executes since t1 sleeps for 1 second ***/
            } catch(InterruptedException tie) {
                tie.printStackTrace();
            }
        else {
            while(other.isBusy()) { // check if other thread is still working
                System.out.println("Waiting!");
                // must synchronize to wait on other object
                try { synchronized(other) { other.wait(); } }
                // note we have synchronized on the object we are going to wait on
                catch(InterruptedException tie) { tie.printStackTrace(); }
                System.out.println("All threads done!");
                /*** Sysout here since this mod allows only one pass ***/
            }
            System.out.println("Wrapping up..."); /*** Lets user know that finishing will take a moment. ***/
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException tie) {
                tie.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Finished!");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ForkExample t1 = new ForkExample(0, null);
        ForkExample t2 = new ForkExample(1, t1);
        (new Thread(t2)).start();
        (new Thread(t1)).start();
        System.out.println("End of Main method"); /*** Added sysout to see how threads work ***/
    }

}
```

This is the output:

```
End of Main method
Still busy, Waiting!
yo
sup
stop synchronization
hey
hello
que?
yes
All threads done!
Thread is no longer busy, Wrapping up...
hey again
Finished!
```

Why is it that the third `notify()` is the only time it goes through?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `Thread#sleep(long)` does not relinquish any acquired locks on objects.

Your application is basically one big race condition and happens at the discretion of the thread scheduler.

The only `notify()` that will matter is the one that happens *after* the `wait()`. The [javadoc of `notify()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify--) states

> The awakened thread will not be able to proceed until the current thread relinquishes the lock on this object.

So, regardless of which one actually wakes up the other thread, that other thread will still have to wait inside the `synchronized` block until the calling thread release the lock, ie. leave the `synchronized` block (and doesn't enter another `synchronized` block).